# Access Calculated Control Returning #NAME?

Tags: ms-access

Below is the calculation I have in a control in access form but it returns #NAME?
If you could possibly help me figure out what I left out or didn't put in, I would greatly appreciate it.  It does not error on save for the control, but when viewing it isn't calculating.

```
=IIf([tbl_Worksheet]![WItemRate]=0,Round(((1+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU])*([tbl_Worksheet]![WALHP]*[tblPSheet]![PRHMPY]*[tblPSheet]![PRABAS])+([tbl_Worksheet]![WAMP]*[tblPSheet]![PRMMPY]*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))+([tbl_Worksheet]![WASubT]*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))),2),Round(((1+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU])*([tbl_Worksheet]![WALHP]*[tblPSheet]![PRHMPY]*([tbl_Worksheet]![WItemRate]))+([tbl_Worksheet]![WAMP]*[tblPSheet]![PRMMPY]*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))+([tbl_Worksheet]![WASubT]*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))),2))
```

Comment: Seem to be missing field names: `*([tbl_ALHP]*` and `+([tbl_AMP]*` and `+([tbl_ASubT]*`. Probably don't need table name prefixes as long as field names are not duplicated in multiple tables/queries in the form RecordSource.

Comment: Thank you!!  I made the correction, same #NAME?.  I was pulling from a form but I guess the renamed fields from tbl to W didn't go in to the form.

Comment: =IIf([tbl_ItemRate]=0,Round((((1+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU])*([tbl_Worksheet]![WALHP]*([tblPSheet]![PRHMPY]*([tblPSheet]![PRABAS]))+([tbl_Worksheet]![WAMP]*[tblPSheet]![PRMMPY]*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))+([tbl_Worksheet]![WASubT]*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))),2),Round(((1+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU])*([tbl_Worksheet]![WALHP]*[tblPSheet]![PRHMPY]*([tbl_ItemRate]))+([tbl_Worksheet]![WAMP]*[tblPSheet]![PRMMPY]*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))+([tbl_Worksheet]![WASubT]*(1+[tblPSheet]![PRABMU]+[tblPSheet]![PRAVGMU]))),2)),""))

Comment: And another `*([tbl_ItemRate]))+` - is that a table or field name? The other 3 are no longer in expression.

Comment: I missed that one.  There are two tables and  that was a field name in a table.  I have changed it to WItemRate

Comment: And now it works?

Comment: no not yet, it works in excel though lol.  I'm trying to convert it to access

Comment: Did you change both [tbl_ItemRate]?

Comment: yes I did change all.

Comment: Well, if referenced fields are actually in form RecordSource, expression should work.

Comment: I was pulling from two different tables for the calculation.  Is that possibly the reason it doesn't work?

Comment: Tables must be in form RecordSource. If they aren't, then the fields are not available.

Answer (score 0):

You expression is not valid due to many errors. Try to reduce it to:

```
=Round((1+[PRAVGMU])*([tbl_ALHP]*[PRHMPY]*IIf([tbl_ItemRate]=0,[PRABAS],[tbl_ItemRate])+[tbl_AMP]*[PRMMPY]*(1+[PRABMU]+[PRAVGMU])+[tbl_ASubT]*(1+[PRABMU]+[PRAVGMU])),2)
```

However, as we don't know what you attempt to calculate, some parentheses may have to be adjusted.